# FSEventStream errors when using xcodebuild - related to Mail?

Tags: xcodebuild

Since upgrading to OSX 10.10, I have been getting these odd errors when running xcodebuild, the following in the terminal output:

> xcodebuild[6484] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart:
>   register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)
>
> xcodebuild[6484] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamInvalidate():
>   failed assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> xcodebuild[6484] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamRelease(): failed
>   assertion 'streamRef != NULL'
>
> xcodebuild[6484:104132]  DVTFilePathFSEvents: Failed to start fs event
>   stream.

This hasn't been a particular problem, as my scripts will just continue and xcodebuild is fine, however today I found that some apps that use xcodebuild (like TestFlight) will see this as an error and stop working.

I tailed the system log and found the culprit may be Mac Mail, with constant entries like this:

> fseventsd[20]: implementation_added_client : failed to add client for
>   path /Users/mok9/Library/Mail/V2/IMAP-...[removed full path for
>   privacy]...

Quitting Mac Mail caused this issue in xcodebuild to go away... that was not a dependency I was expecting!

So, is the Mail issue just a symptom of another problem, or is Mail setting up some issue that causes xcodebuild to be affected?    I suppose I am less concerned about the Mail issue and more concerned with what causes Xcode to be affected by this issue...

Comment: There are no current answers for this issue. I think my iCloud Sync could be causing it.